# React “no-unused-vars” and property undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Because I just started to learn JavaScript I don't seem to solve this issue of unused-vars and property undefined.

I'm using ES6 with arrow functions and context API instead of props

There are 4 folders with complaints about no-unused-vars. They seem to be the only issues breaking the code. I have tried to disable it by using  "// eslint-disable-next-line" with no success.

I am new to JavaScript so I appreciate all the help.

The errors are:

- ***Cannot read property 'user' of undefined***
- ***'dispatch' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars***

```js
export default function App(){
 
  const [{user, token}, dispatch] = useDataLayerValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    const hash = getTokenFromUrl();
    window.location.hash = "";
    const _token = hash.access_token;

    if (_token) {
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_TOKEN",
        token: token,
      });

      spotify.setAccessToken(_token);
      spotify.getMe().then((user) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: user
        });
      });

      spotify.getUserPlaylists().then((playlists) => {
        dispatch({
          type:"SET_PLAYLISTS",
          playlists: playlists,
        });
      });

      spotify.getPlaylist('37i9dQZEVXcGE3bYuPUwd6?si=FFY51lL3QUK21r_TYY14RQ').then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_DISCOVER_WEEKLY",
          discover_weekly: response,
        });
      });
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {token ?  <Player /> : <Login/> }
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
***this is the file with the useDataLayerValue const***

import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer} from "react";

export const DataLayerContext = createContext();

export const DataLayer = ({ initialState, reducer, children}) => (
  <DataLayerContext.Provider  value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </DataLayerContext.Provider>
);

export const useDataLayerValue = () => useContext(DataLayerContext);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you log what `useDataLayerValue();` returns? Looks like it's not returning what you expect

Comment: so i loged the file with the useDataLayerValue

Answer (score 0):

**Cannot read property 'user' of undefined:** This happens, because with

```
const DataLayerContext = createContext();
const useDataLayerValue = () => useContext(DataLayerContext);
```

you are creating a context providing an empty object. And empty objects don't have members called `user`. They don't have any members at all. I guess you set this member afterwards, so you have to check for unset `user` wherever you want to use it. Or you can also provide a default-object in the beginning like so:

```
const defaultDataLayerContext = {user: 'some default user'};
const DataLayerContext = createContext(defaultDataLayerContext);
const useDataLayerValue = () => useContext(DataLayerContext);
```

**'dispatch' is assigned a value but never used**: This is a warning of eslint and it says that

```
const [{user, token}, dispatch] = useDataLayerValue();
```

defines `dispatch`, but you don't use it in your code. So either delete `dispatch` or configure your eslint to not show this warning.